# StackOverflowError on encoding to JSON with circe

Tags: json, scala, stack-overflow, encoder, circe

I am writing tests for my case classes and in the following test I have a StackOverflowError:

```
  test("ValuationRequest - Conversion between case object and Json works") {
    val caseObject = ValuationRequest(TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY, "", IntraDayIntervals.MIN_5)
    val jsonString = caseObject
      .asJson
      .printWith(Printer.noSpaces)

    decode[ValuationRequest](jsonString) must be(Right(caseObject))
  }
```

here's the stacktrace:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at io.circe.syntax.package$EncoderOps$.asJson$extension(package.scala:10)
    at eventbus.ValuationRequest$.$anonfun$encodeRequest$1(ValuationRequestCases.scala:14)
....
```

This is the case code:

```
import AV_Enums.TimeSeriesFunctions.TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY
import AV_Enums.{IntraDayInterval, IntraDayIntervals, TimeSeriesType}
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

case class ValuationRequest(function: TimeSeriesType = TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY, symbol: String, interval: IntraDayInterval = IntraDayIntervals.MIN_5)

object ValuationRequest {
  implicit val encodeRequest: Encoder[ValuationRequest] = Encoder.instance { case response@ValuationRequest(_, _, _) => response.asJson }
  implicit val decodeRequest: Decoder[ValuationRequest] = deriveDecoder[ValuationRequest].widen
}
```

These are the enums it uses:

```
sealed abstract class TimeSeriesType(val text: String) extends EnumEntry {}

sealed abstract class IntraDayInterval(val text: String) extends EnumEntry {}

object TimeSeriesFunctions extends Enum[TimeSeriesType] with CirceEnum[TimeSeriesType] {
  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[TimeSeriesType] = findValues

  case object TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_DAILY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_DAILY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY")

  case object TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY extends TimeSeriesType("TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY")

}

object IntraDayIntervals extends Enum[IntraDayInterval] with CirceEnum[IntraDayInterval] {
  val values: immutable.IndexedSeq[IntraDayInterval] = findValues

  case object MIN_1 extends IntraDayInterval("1min")

  case object MIN_5 extends IntraDayInterval("5min")

  case object MIN_15 extends IntraDayInterval("15min")

  case object MIN_30 extends IntraDayInterval("30min")

  case object MIN_60 extends IntraDayInterval("60min")

}
```

I don't understand what is going on with this case, all the others work fine and are implemented the same way. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problematic line

```
Encoder.instance { case response@ValuationRequest(_, _, _) => response.asJson }
```

`.asJson` here requires `Encoder[ValuationRequest]` which is a recursive call. Any reason you cannot use `deriveEncoder[ValuationRequest]`?

Comment: To be honest no. I was following some guides, and everything worked like that until this one case. I did not go through to see what asJson actually does... silly to assume it was a "simple operation". Thanks for your help!